# Difference between Logitech X56 H.O.T.A.S and H.O.T.A.S Rhino

Tags: controllers, flight-simulator-x, flight-control-hd

I am considering buying a controller for aircraft simulation.

Is there a difference between the Logitech X56 H.O.T.A.S, and Logitech X-56 H.O.T.A.S Rhino?

I see a difference in price, but they look the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rhino ones are the older, rebranded Saitek HOTAS. They're no longer made, which is why they're more expensive. The newer one (non-rhino) also fixes some issues with the older model.